# Overload double equal operator in struct?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct coord {
 int x;
 int y;
  bool operator== (const coord &c1) {
   return (x == c1.x && y == c1.y);
  }
};

int main() {
 coord xy1 = {12, 20};
 coord xy2 = {12, 20};
 cout << xy1 == xy2 << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

I have the code above and the compiler is throwing incomprehensible errors. I can't quite figure out how to overload the == operator in a struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a pair of parens:

```
cout << ( xy1 == xy2 ) << endl;
```

otherwise this is parsed as:

```
(cout << xy1) == xy2
```